# Continuous $f$ analytic in domain without circle, analytic on all of domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the unit circle, and $D$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$. If $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, and $f$ is analytic in $D \setminus S$, must $f$ be analytic on $D$?

Comment: What about $f(z)=1/(z-1)$?

Comment: Yes, Morera says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_0 \in S \cap D$. We can find a fractional linear transformation $g$ so that $g$ maps $S$ onto $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, and $z_0$ maps to $0$. Then $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ if and only if $g \circ f$ is analytic at $0$. However, $g \circ f$ is continuous on $g(D)$ and is analytic on $g(D)\setminus \mathbb{R}$.

> **Theorem (Gamelin,** ***Complex Analysis***, **p. 121).** *Suppose that $f(z)$ is a continuous function on a domain $D$ that is analytic on $D\setminus \mathbb{R}$, that is, on the part of $D$ not lying on the real axis. Then $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$.*

We can then use the theorem on p. 121 of Gamelin's *Complex Analysis* to argue that $g \circ f$ must be analytic at $0$, so $f$ is analytic throughout $D$.